# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <svg> in <nav> in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

[image]

I am getting above error in my code. The code is

```
{ !get_cookie('token') ?
   <div className="sign-in-option"><Link href="/signin" className="nav-item">Signin</Link></div> :
   <svg className="icon icon-Vector">
     <use xlinkHref="/images/svg/sprite/sprite.svg#icon-Vector"></use>
   </svg>
}
```

If i remove cookie condition i will not get above error. From the error i understand that rendered Html is not able to match to the html returned by server. As get_cookie is a method to get cookie stored on browser. So server is returning something else.

How can i fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly mentioned, the HTML rendered on the browser doesn't match the one generated on the server. To solve it you can move the value of `get_cookie('token')` to state and update it inside a `useEffect`.

```js
const Header = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        setToken(get_cookie('token'))
    }, [])

    return !token ? (
        <div className="sign-in-option">
            <Link href="/signin" className="nav-item">Signin</Link>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <svg className="icon icon-Vector">
            <use xlinkHref="/images/svg/sprite/sprite.svg#icon-Vector"></use>
        </svg>
    )
}
```

Comment: using this method the above error is resolved but on initial render it shows "Signin" and then after few seconds it change to svg icon. Is their any way that it shows svg on initial render also.

Comment: You'd have to handle the token cookie server-side for that.